# SwiftUI: How to combine .toggle() not Toggle(isOn..) with UserDefault

Tags: swiftui, toggle, userdefaults

Currently I have

```
@Published var isVisited: Bool {
        didSet{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(isVisited,forKey: "isVisited")
        }
    }
    init() {
        self.isVisited = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isVisited") as? Bool ?? false
    }
```

```
@State private var edit = false
@ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

Button(action: { self.edit.toggle()}) {
                    if self.edit {
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill").font(.title)
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "heart").font(.title)
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(.red)
```

Ideally, whenever the "heart" icon is tapped, it will be filled and save data to UserDefault database. I only know the uses of Toggle(isOn:..).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```swift
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        isVisited = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isVisited")
    }

    @Published var isVisited: Bool {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(isVisited, forKey: "isVisited")
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.userSettings.isVisited.toggle() }) {
            if self.userSettings.isVisited {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill").font(.title)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart").font(.title)
            }
        }.foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

What I did here is that every time `UserSettings` loads I load `isVisited` from UserDefaults and then whenever that property is set it updates `UserDefaults`.

Then on the view instead of using `@State` to hold the data I'm getting the data directly from `UserSettings`, since it will have the most updated data.

Comment: wow!! I did the same thing and it didn't work, maybe I left the $ like self.$userSettings.isVisited.toggle() !! Thank you so much @Daniel Amarante

Comment: You can remove `init` and do: `@Published var isVisited = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isVisited") { ... }`

Comment: by the way @ Daniel Amarante and @pawello2222, if I want to display the saved data to another view then what is the way to do it? I don't really want to use CoreData for just this guy

Comment: @DucDang This is another question :) Please create a new post and describe your issue there.

Comment: @DucDang You can share the same instance of `UserSettings` as an environment object, then all changes to it will happen in all screens.